# Cygwin creates stackdump file, takes long to compile (C++)

Tags: c++, g++, cygwin

I am trying to compile the following problem (downloads.cpp) in C++ using Cygwin:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int N, ft = 0, bw = 0;
ifstream input;
input.open("downloads.in");
input >> N; 
pair <int, int> S_T[N+1];
S_T[N+1].first = INT_MAX;
S_T[N+1].second = INT_MAX;
int FT[N];
fill(FT, FT + sizeof(FT), 0);
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    input >> S_T[i].first >> S_T[i].second;
}
input.close();
sort(S_T, S_T + N);

for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    if (S_T[i+1].second != 0) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < N; ++j) {
            S_T[j].second -= S_T[i].second;
        }
        S_T[i+1].first += S_T[i].first;
        S_T[i+1].second *= S_T[i-1].second / S_T[i].second;
    } else if (S_T[i+1].first != INT_MAX && S_T[i+1].second != INT_MAX)  {
        S_T[i+1].first += S_T[i].first;
        S_T[i+1].second *= S_T[i-1].second / S_T[i].second;
    }
    FT[i] = S_T[i].second;
}

for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    ft += FT[i];

ofstream output;
output.open("downloads.out");
output << ft << endl;
output.close();

return 0;
```

}

And I get the following error (with varying 5-digit numbers after "downloads"):

```
0 [main] downloads 76188 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to downloads.exe.stackdump
 [Finished in 6.5s]
```

Additionally, the program takes significantly longer than the usual one second to compile, and Cygwin seems to create a .exe.stackdump file with the same name as my program in the same file.

I have already checked for Cygwin opening background processes, and have found none. Anyone know why this could be happening?

Comment: The first thing to do is to look at the actual stack dump. It will tell you where the problem happened.

Comment: `pair <int, int> S_T[N+1];` is not right.

Comment: @RSahu What is the mistake there?

Comment: @JohnAlexandropoulos, the sizes of array must be known at compile time. `N` is a variable. It's value is not known at compile time. I am guessing that g++ allows variable length arrays as an extension. It is not standard C++ though.